# how to get rid of warning `RuntimeWarning: A loop is being detached from a child watcher with pending handlers`

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

if I use asyncio to spawn subprocess which run another python script, there is warning at the end: `RuntimeWarning: A loop is being detached from a child watcher with pending handlers`, if the subprocess is terminate by terminate().

For example a very simple dummy:

```
import datetime
import time
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(3):
        msg = 'pid({}) {}: continue'.format(os.getpid(), datetime.datetime.now())
        print(msg)
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Then I spawn the dummy:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import subprocess
T = 3 # if the T=5, which allows the thread to finish, then there is no such warning.
async def handle_proc():
    p = None
    try:
        p = await subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(
            'python3', 'dummy.py',
            #'dummy.sh'
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(T)
    finally:
        if p and p.returncode is None:
            p.terminate()
        print('handle_proc Done!')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(handle_proc())
```

There will be the warning, if T is short enough to allow p.terminate() get called.

if I spawn a bash script there is no warning:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
N=10
T=1
for i in $(seq 1 $N)
do
    echo "loop=$i/$N, sleep $T"
    >&2 echo "msg in stderror: ($i/$N,$T)"
    sleep $T
done
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this warning, you need to `await p.wait()` after `p.terminate()`.

The reason you need to do this is that `p.terminate()` only sends `signal.SIGTERM` to the process. The process might still do some cleanup work after receiving the signal. If you don't wait for the process to finish terminating, your script finishes before the process and the process is cut off prematurely.